# how to configure apache on XP for python 2.6.2 and what do you prefer, python with framework/without?

Tags: python, apache, windows-xp

I am starting python today. It will be my pleasure to have your help.

Comment: Prefer implies opinion, this should be a community wiki.

Comment: yes seems that, but i like expertise preference for me.

Comment: If expertise is what you want, you should ask your apache question over on serverfault.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About a framework - choose the one you'll like. You can find most of them on [Python wiki](http://wiki.python.org/moin/WebFrameworks).

About Apache - if you choose a framework, it'll probably have some kind of development web server built-in, with better debugging capabilities than Apache installation. If you really want Apache, then you could [install](http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/InstallationOnWindows) and [configure](http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/QuickConfigurationGuide) [mod_wsgi](http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/).

Answer (score 0):

If you are starting Python today, why tackle web development immediately? I'd start off with "hello world" in the console.

Comment: thats good, i can start as you. My target is web development with python, so today or tomorrow i must know that.

Comment: Seems you are planning to learn Python rather quickly. Good luck.

Comment: exactly, i need to jump for development immediately.